# Css issue - li is getting unknown margin?

Tags: html, css

I am working on an HTML CSS template, i stuck in a situation in which my list item (li) is getting bottom-margin from somewhere, here is my code:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/tepozipokipa/1/edit)

**HTML**

```
<div id="main-4">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="http://demo.htmlcoder.me/ivega/images/portfolio-1.jpg" alt="#">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://demo.htmlcoder.me/ivega/images/portfolio-2.jpg" alt="#">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://demo.htmlcoder.me/ivega/images/portfolio-3.jpg" alt="#">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://demo.htmlcoder.me/ivega/images/portfolio-4.jpg" alt="#">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-4 ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 337px;
}

    #main-4 ul li > img {
        width: 337px;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because images do that. give your images `vertical-align:bottom` and see how it's being fixed:

```
#main-4 ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 337px;
}

    #main-4 ul li > img {
        width: 337px;
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }
```